# How to expand a particular node in YUI treeview

Tags: yui

I want to expand a particular node on click of a string in YUI. I have used YUI treeview and
I am preparing a string of nodes that satisfies search criteria.Now, I want to expand those nodes on click on each string .

Can anyone help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the focus() event, as it causes the node focused to automatically expand.
There is also a method toggle(), which might help.
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/treeview/